# Вывод stacktrace от Exception и Thread

Tags: java

Недавно обнаружил, что stacktrace, вызываемый у `Exception` на один метод короче, чем stacktrace вызываемый у `Thread`. Почему то `Exception` не добавляет в конец stacktrace сам метод `getStackTrace()`. Кто-нибудь может объяснить почему так происходит?

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = new Exception().getStackTrace();


StackTraceElement [] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = new Exception().getStackTrace();
```

Это в мейн треде вызывается

```
StackTraceElement [] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

Это в другом треде. В стектрейсе дополнительно указывает информацию, что это за тред. Отсюда и дополнительный элемент в массиве